# angular js: splitting up a large controller into multiple files

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-service, angularjs-controller

I have a controller that is getting rather large.. mostly due to all the input validation I need to do.  What I'd like to do is split out all the validation functions into a separate "partial controller".

Normally, I would just create a service and move all the functions in there (which I may still do).  The only problem I have with that is:  the validation functions, occasionally, need to be aware of the scope.  For example, when I'm doing cross validations.  I'm not sure I want to pass the scope to the service.

**What would be the best approach to this problem?  Use a service..?**

```
.service("validation-service", function() {
    return {
        populate: function($scope) { //return validator functions }
    };
});
```

**Or, is there a way to separate the controller into two files?  Something like this..**

#### File 1

```
.partialController("myController", function($scope) { /*do normal stuff here*/ });
```

#### File 2

```
.partialController("myController", function($scope) { /*do validations here*/ });
```

Comment: You should try to reduce the dependency on `$scope` since everything get exposed you cannot keep the service validation generic. Maybe passing a object created using scope properties is better as it would make dependency explicit like `populate:function (param1, param2, param3)`

Comment: agreed, that's why I don't want to do it in a service - I'd rather split my controller into 2 files..  The validations aren't really reusable - they're pretty specific to the 1 application.

Comment: why not create a form managing directive or controller to handle the validations?

Comment: part of my solution is a directive.. and a service.  The directive sets the "validation set", i.e `validation-set="firstname"`.  The set is just a list of functions that get populated within the controller, and added via `addSet()` to the service.  They're in the controller because they're (the validation functions) reliant on the scope (sometimes).  For example, start date must be less than end date - so if start date changes i need to trigger validation on end date.  I'm doing this via a `watch`.

Comment: Here's a fiddle of what I have so far:  http://jsfiddle.net/5ca4D/1/  It's a little verbose and not complete, but might help shed some light on what I'm trying to do.

Comment: Is there not a way you can move some of these validations into directives? That's optimally where validations should go...

Comment: yeah, but there's a ton of them.  I end up with 10 attributes on a DOM element - I don't like the looks of that.

Answer (score 1):

I would have to agree with Jeff directives will be a lot more useful and possibly reusable if you break it down to its basic function.

For example you could build a password confirm directive or a semantically different directive that checks for equality.

Check out this equality directive, it should help:
http://plnkr.co/edit/bTFMzV70vjOzwhimVtQL?p=info

---

For the example in your Fiddle you could do this instead: (though I am sure you fiddle was a simplified example)

```
<input name='start' type="number" ng-model="model.start" max="{{model.end}}"/>
<input name='end' type="number" ng-model="model.end" min="{{model.start}}"/>
```

Comment: yup, it was a simplified example.. I had originally written a bunch of directives, but that turned into an attribute nightmare.

Comment: Yeah then a service would do it, which ever is more maintainable & more easily understood.